# ARC related crash in iOS when using a block pointer as a member variable

Tags: ios, memory-management, crash, block, automatic-ref-counting

Can anyone please help with ARC and memory-related crashes?

I have class `LTRequest` with a member variable that stores a block pointer:

```
typedef void (^APICallOKBlock)(id);

@interface LTRequest : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) APICallOKBlock okCB;
@end
```

The code to initialize that variable:

```
-(void)addOKBlock:(APICallOKBlock)okBlock
{
    self.okCB = okBlock;
}
```

I call the block in case of success:

```
-(void)apiCallCompletedWithResult:(id)result
{
    if(self.okCB != nil)
    {
        self.okCB(result);
    }
}
```

For reference, the block looks something like this:

```
APICallOKBlock okBlock = ^(id result)
{
    [self handleAPICallCompleted:result];
};
```

It calls a function defined in the object that scheduled the api call, however that part is not important. Important is what happens when `apiCallCompletedWithResult` is called after the api call has been successful. And what happens is that the block gets called but the app crashes shortly afterwards when the request object `LTRequest` gets deallocated (SomeAppName is our application):

```
Thread 6 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.low-priority
Thread 6 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x300bad9c objc_release + 12
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x300c6c00 objc_storeStrong + 24
2   SomeAppName                     0x00055688 -[LTRequest .cxx_destruct] (LTRequest.m:12)
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x300bba66 object_cxxDestructFromClass + 50
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x300bba2c object_cxxDestruct + 8
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x300b99ac objc_destructInstance + 20
```

I tried to use `unsafe_unretained` instead of `strong` to store the block in the `LTRequest` object:

```
@property (nonatomic, unsafe_unretained) APICallOKBlock okCB;
```

In that case the crash happens exactly in the line with the if:

```
Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x300b9eda objc_retain + 10
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x300c6bde objc_retainAutoreleasedReturnValue + 34
2   SomeAppName                     0x00054f90 -[LTRequest apiCallCompletedWithResult:] (LTRequest.m:84)
3   SomeAppName                     0x0002f8aa __29-[LTServerProxy makeAPICall:]_block_invoke_0 (LTServerProxy.m:154)

// file LTRequest.m

line 84    if(self.okCB != nil)
line 85    {
line 86        self.okCB(result);
line 87    }
```

Am I using the pointer to a block properly and how should I call it to not cause any crashes?

Some info: I am using iOS SDK 5.0, deployment target is 4.0, device iPhone, and ARC is enabled for the whole project.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You want the property to be `copy` rather than `retain`:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) APICallOKBlock okCB;
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! Not sure why developer doc consistently mentions only the new strong/weak attributes and fails to remind that some of the older ones may still be needed.

Comment: http://blog.refractalize.org/post/10476042560/copy-vs-retain-for-objective-c-blocks has some notes on why this is the case, and a link to an even more detailed article.

Comment: This saved me! I had an NSNumber that I had accidentally marked as nonatomic, assign instead of nonatomic, strong! Big difference! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to copy the block when saving its instance to the class instance.

```
-(void)addOKBlock:(APICallOKBlock)okBlock
{
    self.okCB = [okBlock copy];
}
```

Comment: Thanks, good suggestion but setting the copy property attribute is more straightforward (no need to copy in each place when the variable is assigned)